# SQL - search a date-time period that doesn't exists in the table records

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Need an expert opinion here:

I am trying to implement a scenario in one of our project which displays the graph based on user input and one of the input is date-time range. Let me describe with an example.

Consider an example where there are records having `start-date-time = 2011-09-28 9:30` and `end-date-time = 2011-09-28 11:30`. Let's say an user is trying to view a graph for date-time-range of `2011-09-28 10:00 to 2011-09-28 11:00` - now the system should show a graph since the data is available for the given period (since 10 - 11 is within 9.30 - 11.30).

How can I implement this scenario and how do I search for such inputs?

Note:
There might be too many rows for a particular date/date-time

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table tb
WHERE 
  (  user_start_time <= tb.start_date_time AND 
     user_end_time >= tb.start_date_time
  ) OR (
     user_start_time <= tb.end_date_time AND 
     user_end_time >= tb.end_date_time
  ) OR (
     user_start_time >= tb.start_date_time AND 
     user_end_time <= tb.end_date_time
  )
```

Comment: @Macro will this work for the above values? Both condition fails 1st one for `user_start_time` and the 2nd one for `user_end_time`

Comment: `-` means arithmetic subtraction. You should either remove it from the names or escape it.

Comment: @Andriy M: yes, I know and you're right, but I used that names because OP named fields in that way in his post. Anyway, I've just edited my post. Thanks

Comment: I see, but you could simply put backticks around to preserve the names. Still, replacing hyphens with underscores is possibly a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on whether you need to ensure that the entire date range entered by the user is covered by a graph in your table. If you need this then you'll have to ensure that both the user start time and user end time are between the values in the database. Hence:

```
select * from graph_table t
where @user_start_time between t.graph_range_start and t.graph_range_end
and @user_end_time between t.graph_range_start and t.graph_range_end
limit 1;
```

You'll have to decide how to cater for multiple rows coming back (I've just used LIMIT 1 here).

If you want to bring back any graphs that cover either the user start time or user end time then change the 'and' in the query to an 'or', Hence:

```
select * from graph_table t
where (@user_start_time between t.graph_range_start and t.graph_range_end)
or (@user_end_time between t.graph_range_start and t.graph_range_end)
limit 1;
```

Again, you'll have to decide how you want to handle multiple results here.

Comment: Interesting. I am expecting just two points (two records) `x` and `y` and your first option works very well, but for an input with higher `end_time` will create a problem - how should I solve that? For ex: if the input is `10 - 11.45` for the above scenario how should I get two records.

Comment: using the 10 - 11.45 example I guess the answer is: do you want to bring back any data? Given that you have 9.30 -11.30 in the database and the user has requested an end time of 11.45 if you use the 9.30 - 11.30 data then you will be returning data that does not cover the whole time range specified by the user i.e. between 11.30 and 11.45 will be missing. PS Could you put up some basic example data for the table to be queried, please? It'll help when trying to write example queries! Thanks.

Comment: Yes it doesn't satisfy the given date-range but it will be used to draw the line from `x` to `y` - & I will use some kind of highlighting to show the range specified by the user.

Comment: actually speaking I don't have the actual data since it's a work in progress and we are in phase of writing the code, for now I have been using my own data to satisfy various needs. SORRY

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM TableName 
WHERE (@StartDate >=  start-date-time AND @StartDate <= end-date-time) 
OR 
(@EndDate >= start-date-time AND @EndDate <= end-date-time)
```

Comment: This will work for the above input values what if the user inputs `10 to 11.45`? Something greater than the existing one. Remember I want to fetch both records so that I can draw the graph.

Comment: @RakeshS : If you want to get record if it's start point or end point are within date range then check my updated query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table tb
WHERE NOT (
    tb.start_date_time > user_end_time 
  AND 
    tb.end_date_time < user_start_time
)
```

Try this.
Contains the following scenarios and returns results: 
    condition (searched interval): 
    user_start_time = 2011-09-28 9:30 and user_end_time = 2011-09-28 11:30

- tb.start_date_time = 2011-09-28 08:30 and tb.end_date_time =
  2011-09-28 12:30
- tb.start_date_time = 2011-09-28 10:30 and tb.end_date_time =
  2011-09-28 11:00
- tb.start_date_time = 2011-09-28 10:30 and tb.end_date_time =
  2011-09-28 12:30
- tb.start_date_time = 2011-09-28 08:30 and tb.end_date_time =
  2011-09-28 10:30

Exceptions:

- tb.start_date_time = 2011-09-28 07:30 and tb.end_date_time =
  2011-09-28 08:30
- tb.start_date_time = 2011-09-28 12:30 and tb.end_date_time =
  2011-09-28 13:30